# How can I have an out ViewData Parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have some repetitive `ViewData` data that I need them in several `controllers`. I'd like to create a utility function for that. I'm trying to have an `out` parameter and call the function with controller's `ViewData`.

Can someone please guide about the correct syntax and approach to do this?

```
public static void GetSheetsEssentialViewData(out ViewDataDictionary ViewData)
{
    ViewData["111"] = Utility.111();
    ViewData["22"] = Utility.22();
    ViewData["33"] = Utility.33();
    .....
}
```

Comment: Well currently you're not *initializing* that parameter. Why do you need it to be `out` at all? Can't you just pass in the view data from the controller, and let the method modify it? (I'd also recommend calling it `viewData` to follow normal naming conventions.)

Comment: How can I pass the view data from the controller? I thought it's the only way to do it.

Comment: Can't you just call `UtilityClass.GetSheetsEssentialViewData(ViewData)`?

Comment: I've never tried to call it. In the function itself I get the error: `Error 4 The out parameter 'ViewData' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method`

Comment: As I said, it shouldn't be an `out` parameter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an error because an `out` parameter has to be initialized in the method before you use it - it's initially unassigned. However, I don't think you want it to be an `out` parameter at all.

You can just pass the existing reference from the controller, not using an `out` parameter at all:

```
// In UtilityClass
public static void GetSheetsEssentialViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData)
```

Then in a controller method:

```
UtilityClass.GetSheetsEssentialViewData(ViewData);
```

Or you might consider making it an extension method:

```
public static void PopulateSheetsData(this ViewDataDictionary viewData)
```

Then you in your controller you can just call it with:

```
ViewData.PopulateSheetsData();
```

which is very readable, IMO.

(To find out more about `ref` and `out` parameters, you might want to read [my article about C# parameter passing](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html).)